# CSS Mobile Nav Dropdown - Alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this responsive nav I found on codepen.io. It works nicely on codepen.io however not so much in JS Fiddle (Included Below). When the screen is dragged over the 3 lines for the drop down icon link gets all wonky, it is not aligned propertly with the rest of the navigation. Also whenever there is a dropdown in use, the options no not align on top of each other (desktop or mobile). Related Dropdown CSS is below - Any help is appreciated Thanks. I put it into a JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z8rxe922/4/).

```
    // Dropdown list
      ul li {
        min-width: 190px;
        a {
          padding: 15px;
          line-height: 20px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Dropdown list binds to JS toggle event
.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

/* Mobile navigation */

// Binds to JS Toggle
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: $nav-background;
  height: $nav-height;
  width: $nav-height;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: $breakpoint) {
  // Hamburger nav visible on mobile only
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
   width: 100%;
    padding: $nav-height 0 15px;
    ul {
      display: none;
      li {
        float: none;
        a {
          padding: 15px;
          line-height: 20px;
        }
        ul li a {
          padding-left: 30px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
  span,
  span:before,
  span:after {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    background: $nav-font-color;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  }
  span:before {
    top: -10px;
  }
  span:after {
    bottom: -10px;
  }
  &.active span {
    background-color: transparent;
    &:before,
    &:after {
      top: 0;
    }
    &:before {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    &:after {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just fixed JS Fiddle Link.... Again

Comment: what's the original codepen?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvQKGw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an issue with the SCSS. I just copied and pasted it over from your codepen, and it's working fine now in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ngs460s/4/) I forked from your original. I added a negative margin to your `nav-container` class to correct the alignment issue with the toggle button. Additionally, you can use a flexbox to get the center-positioning for your menu items.

```
// Container with no padding for navbar
.nav-container {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}
```

Comment: Perfect, However I believe the issues comes in with some of the edit that I made. I wanted the text to be centered

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z8rxe922/6/ this JS Fiddle has the text centered and the button fixed the only thing is the links in the dropdowns

Comment: Ah, I thought it was just a straight port over from codepen. Hold on.

Comment: Okay. Check out the link now and tell me if that's right

Comment: Look at that. Perfect Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Just two lines of code. Check out [flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you haven't; they're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/z8rxe922/5/

You just have to use position as `relative` instead of `absolute` and in the responsive screen you have to set `padding` to 0.

```
.navmobile {
  position: relative;
  float:right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav { 
    padding:0px;
  }
}
```

What was your second question ? It is a bit unclear.

Comment: Perfect one thing down. The second thing was when you click any dropdown links. The links apear next to each other instead on ontop

Comment: This applies to when it is in mobile and also when it is desktop view. If you click "services" you can see the issue.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/z8rxe922/6 this JS Fiddle has the text centered and the mobile button fixed the only thing is the links in the dropdowns